# Python that returns rows in a file that have too many, or not enough tabs

Tags: python, tabs, csv

I need some python that will do the following:

- Find all the rows in a tab delimited text file that have more than or less than X-number of tabs.
- Print those rows (each row on it's own line of course)

So for example, "the_file.txt" has this content:

```
Field1[TAB]Field2[TAB]Field3[TAB]Field4[TAB]Field5
Field1[TAB]Field2[TAB]Field3
Field1[TAB]Field2[TAB]Field3[TAB]Field4
Field1[TAB]Field2[TAB]Field3[TAB]Field4[TAB]Field5
```

Pseudopython:

```
Read the_file.txt
Find all rows that do not have 4 tabs
Print the entire content of those rows
```

Returns:

```
Field1[TAB]Field2[TAB]Field3
Field1[TAB]Field2[TAB]Field3[TAB]Field4
```

One thing to consider is that the files I want to run the Python against are often very large, always 1000+ rows, often 10,000+ rows, sometimes 100,000+ rows.

Thanks!

Comment: `for line in file: if line.count('\t') != 4: print(line)`

Comment: [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  StackOverflow is a knowledge base for *specific* programming problems -- not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.  Post your coding attempt and the results.

Answer (score 1):

There you go

```
number_not_tabs = 4

with open('the_file.txt') as f:
    content = f.readlines()
# you may also want to remove whitespace characters like `\n` at the end of each line
for x in content:
    if x.count("\t") != number_not_tabs:
        print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```py
df=pd.read_csv('the_file.txt',sep='\t')
df.columns=['Col1','Col2','Col3','Col4','Col5']
nans = lambda df: df[df.isnull().any(axis=1)]

print(nans(df))
```

**Output:**

```py
    Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5
0   Field1  Field2  Field3  NaN     NaN
1   Field1  Field2  Field3  Field4  NaN
```